# How to enumerate combinations of words?

Tags: python, regex, string, combinations, enumerate

Given the text with slashes `definitive/deterministic arithmetic/calculation`, the goal is enumerate the possible combinations of the words, e.g. expected output:

```
definitive arithmetic
deterministic arithmetic
definitive calculation
deterministic calculation
```

Another example, input `voice/speech wave information processing method/technique`, expected otuput:

```
voice wave information processing method
voice wave information processing technique
speech wave information processing method
speech wave information processing technique
```

And sometimes there are brackets, the expected output would be to enumerate outputs with and without the terms inside the bracket, e.g. input `bactericidal/microbidical (nature/properties)`, expected output:

```
bactericidal
microbidical
bactericidal nature
bactericidal properties
microbidical nature
microbidical properties
```

I've tried this that solve the texts with single slash but it's way too hacky, is there a simpler way?

```
for english in inputs:
    if sum([1 for tok in english.split(' ') if '/' in tok]) == 1:
        x = [1 if '/' in tok else 0 for tok in english.split(' ') ]

        left = english.split(' ')[:x.index(1)]
        word = english.split(' ')[x.index(1)].split('/')
        right = english.split(' ')[x.index(1)+1:]

        for tok in word:
            print(' '.join([left + [tok] + right][0]))
```

**How do I also capture the cases with more than one slash?**

Here's a list of possible inputs:

```
definitive/deterministic arithmetic/calculation
random/stochastic arithmetic/calculation
both ends/edges/terminals
to draw/attract/receive attention
strict/rigorous/exact solution
both ends/edges/terminals
easy to conduct/perform/carry out
easy to conduct/perform/carry out
between/among (equals/fellows)
reference/standard/nominal value
one kind/type/variety/species
primary cause/source/origin
to be disordered/disturbed/chaotic
same category/class/rank
while keeping/preserving/maintaining/holding
driving/operating in the reverse/opposite direction
only/just that portion/much
cannot doubt/question/suspect
does not reach/attain/match
tube/pipe/duct axis
recatangular/Cartesian/orthogonal coordinates
tube/pipe/duct wall
acoustic duct/conduit/channel
site of damage/failure/fault
voice/speech wave information processing method/technique
fundamental/basic theorem/proposition
single/individual item/product
one body/unit/entity
first stage/grade/step
time/era of great leaps/strides
one form/shape/figure
reserve/spare circuit/line
basic/base/backing material
set/collection/group of tables
in the form of a thin sheet/laminate/veneer
minute/microscopic pore/gap
forming/molding and working/machining
small amount/quantity/dose
liquid crystal form/state/shape
to rub/grind/chafe the surface
the phenomenon of fracture/failure/collapse
compound/composite/combined effect
molecular form/shape/structure
…st/…nd/….rd/…th group (periodic table)
the architectural/construction world/realm
to seal/consolidate a material by firing/baking
large block/clump/clod
bruned/baked/fired brick
unbruned/unbaked/unfired brick
kiln/furnance/oven surface
stationary/stator vane/blade
moving/rotor vane/blade
industrial kiln/furnance/oven
mean/average pore size/diameter
hardened/cured/set material
kiln/oven/furnance lining
piping (layout/arrangement/system)
metallic luster/brilliance/shine
mechanical treatment/working/processing
thin-sheet/laminate/veneer manufacture
thin sheet/laminate/veneer
vehicle (cars/trucks/trains) field
sheet/panel/plate thickness
corrosion prevention/resistance/protection
wriggling/squirming/slithering motion
method for forming/molding/shaping
object to be molded/formed/shaped
pressurized molding/forming/shaping equipment
premolded/preformed object/body
to seal/consolidate a material by firing/baking
furnance/kiln/oven wall
slipping/sliding/gliding mode
bactericidal/microbidical (nature/properties)
secondary/rechargeable cell/battery
new region/domain/area
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should just be using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can split on spaces and `'/'` which will work for both single words and groups. For example:

```
from itertools import product

s = "definitive/deterministic arithmetic/calculation"
l = [g.split('/') for g in s.split(' ')]
[" ".join(words) for words in product(*l)]
```

**result:**

```
['definitive arithmetic',
 'definitive calculation',
 'deterministic arithmetic',
 'deterministic calculation']
```

or:

```
s = "voice/speech wave information processing method/technique"
l = [g.split('/') for g in s.split(' ')]
[" ".join(words) for words in product(*l)]
```

**result:**

```
['voice wave information processing method',
 'voice wave information processing technique',
 'speech wave information processing method',
 'speech wave information processing technique']
```

Comment: What about the input with brackets?

Answer (score 1):

This will respect brackets in the input. The idea is to replace brackets `(...)` with `/` at the beginning, so `(string1/string2)` will become `/string1/string2`. Then `split('/')` will then create list containing empty string `['', 'string1', 'string2']`. You will then use `itertools.product`:

```
data = [
    'definitive/deterministic arithmetic/calculation',
    'vehicle (cars/trucks/trains) field',
]

import re
from itertools import product

for d in data:
    l = [w.split('/') for w in re.sub(r'\(([^)]+)\)', r'/\1', d).split()]
    print([' '.join(i for i in p if i) for p in product(*l)])
```

Prints:

```
['definitive arithmetic', 'definitive calculation', 'deterministic arithmetic', 'deterministic calculation']
['vehicle field', 'vehicle cars field', 'vehicle trucks field', 'vehicle trains field']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question,here is a regex which can be used to parse your input as needed

> \w+/\w+|\W+\w+|\W+\w+\W+

Using this regex,you can get all the words as you need.In this regex,we place optional conditions to check if the string has optional characters(Like () or some other characters)

You can use re.findall() method to parse the above regex with a text string as example

```
import re

expression="\w+\/\w+|\W+\w+|\W+\w+\W+"

test_string="abcd/efgh(sabdhaksdaksdas)/ijkl/mnop1/qerst/(abcdef)"

print(re.findall(expression,test_string))
```

There might be some issues with this regex.You can use this as a starting point.

After this you can use the itertools.product method from the below answer to get all possible combination of words.